# Resizing output Terminal in C Language

Tags: c

would like to get some help on a c project i am currently working on. I have a string/array of output to the terminal, but somehow the standard terminal is too small for my output. Even after i manually expand the window of the console the output is still cut off, instead of printing in a single line, it just gets cut off and go to the next row automatically.

hope to get help.

Comment: are you talking about line wrapping?

Comment: The C language doesn't know anything about terminals.  You have to name your operating system and development tools to get a usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to correct this is by splitting your one-line output in multiple lines, using "\n" at the end of every line.

By doing this you can control when and where it has to write in the next line, and you can make it look more like you wanted to.